# Premultiplying image alpha efficiently

Tags: c, image-processing, optimization, graphics, cairo

Load a 32bit image into a buffer and I then premultiply the color values with the corresponding alpha to use for blending.

The following works but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, even if it only results in a good-enough approximation?

image data is a pointer of this type:

```
typedef struct rgba_pixel
{
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t a;
} rgba_pixel;

rgba_pixel * image_data;

for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
{
    if ( image_data[i].a == 0 )
        image_data[i].r = image_data[i].g = image_data[i].b = 0;
    else if ( image_data[i].a < 255 )
    {
        alpha_factor = image_data[i].a / 255.0;
        image_data[i].r = image_data[i].r * alpha_factor;
        image_data[i].g = image_data[i].g * alpha_factor;
        image_data[i].b = image_data[i].b * alpha_factor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of image_data's and alpha_factor's types?

Comment: added to definition, alpha_factor is a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your `a`, `r`, `g` and `b` components are `unsigned char`, you can improve performance by turning floating point multiplication to integer multiplication and use `shr 8` (division by 256) instead of dividing by 255:

```
for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
{
    if ( image_data[i].a == 0 )
        image_data[i].r = image_data[i].g = image_data[i].b = 0;
    else if ( image_data[i].a < 255 ) 
    {
        image_data[i].r = (unsigned short)image_data[i].r * image_data[i].a >> 8;
        image_data[i].g = (unsigned short)image_data[i].g * image_data[i].a >> 8;
        image_data[i].b = (unsigned short)image_data[i].b * image_data[i].a >> 8;
    }
}
```

This will convert 1 fp division and 3 fp multiplications into 3 integer multiplications and 3 bit shifts.

Another improvement which can be done is using union struct for the pixel data:

```
typedef union rgba_pixel
{
    struct {
        uint8_t r;
        uint8_t g;
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t a;
    };

    uint32_t u32;
} rgba_pixel;
```

And then assigning zero to r, g and b at once:

```
//image_data[i].r = image_data[i].g = image_data[i].b = 0; 
image_data[i].u32 = 0; //use this instead
```

According to https://godbolt.org/ with `x86-64 gcc 7.2`, the latter generates less instructions at `-O3`. Which of course may or may not be faster in practice.

Another thing to be considered is partial loop unrolling, i.e. processing multiple (for example 4) pixels per loop iteration. If you are guaranteed that your rows are multiples of 4 in width, you do it even without additional checks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give this a shot

Comment: The else if is to avoid doing anything if the alpha is 255, ie. alpha_factor will be 1.0

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. Also I added few additional thoughts.